# Unable to properly format html code to text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a script where I copy and paste information from one url to another.

I was able to get the html code using playwright and beautiful soup but was unable to format properly.

For example,

```
<strong>Autoignition Temperature: </strong>
```

Using html2text, I was able to convert the above html code to

```
AutoignitionTemp = ** Autoignition Temperature: **
```

Which I then paste it into the correct website using this code:

```
pastePage.frame_locator(
    "text=Rich Text Editor, txtContent3Editor toolbarsClipboard/Undo Cut Copy Paste Paste  >> iframe").locator(
    "body").fill(html2text.html2text(AutoignitionTemp))
```

However, txt editor does not recognised the ** as bolding and paste the text directly as it is:

**Pasted Code:**

[image]

**Is there a way I can format the text properly or paste the html code directly into chrome console?**

Comment: *However, txt editor does not recognised the __*__ as bolding* first thing first, what is your text editor? does it support markdown? is there any source mode for the text editor? the problem is not on your python, but your text editor.

Comment: I wonder if it would work to use `<b>` for bold instead of `<strong>`

Comment: @bagusTesa Your comment got me to explore the ckeditor and I managed to found a workaround for the text editor issue. The source button allows me to paste in html code and it will format html code once I clicked it again. Thank you!